Changes in child processes variables not reflected in parent object
I have a parent class in Python that can start a process in a child class. The child class has a multiprocessing.Process that changes some variables. I would expect changes to be visible for the parent class since the object is created there, but somehow, the variables are not shared. The process is started as a fork.
Here is an example code:
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
import time

class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        print(multiprocessing.get_start_method())
        self.child = Child()

    def start(self):
        self.child.start_child()

    def print_child_variable(self):
        print('Parent: Child Variable: ' + str(self.child.some_variable))


class Child:

    def __init__(self):
        self.some_variable = None
        self.status = False

    def start_child(self):
        self.status = True

        do_something_process = Process(target=self.do_something)
        do_something_process.start()
    

    def do_something(self):
        self.some_variable = True
        print('Child: some variable after changing: ' + str(self.some_variable))

    def print_some_variable(self):
        print('Child: some variable: ' + str(self.some_variable))
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent = Parent()
    parent.print_child_variable()
    time.sleep(1)
    parent.start()
    parent.print_child_variable()
    time.sleep(1)
    parent.print_child_variable()
    time.sleep(1)
    parent.child.print_some_variable()

The output:
fork
Parent: Child Variable None
Parent: Child Variable None
Child: some variable after chaging True
Parent: Child Variable None
Child: some variable None

I would expect that after the change, the variable some_variable will be true even if checked from the parent object. Can anyone help me understand what is going on?

Normal variables are not synchronized between processes. To exchange data you can use a pool with a mapping function and return values or the special objects from the multiprocessing library.

When you use multiprocessing, the child process is a completely different process from the original.  There is no sharing unless you explicitly set it up.

Note that this question is horribly obfuscated by mixing the terms parent/child, once in the context of processes and once in the names of two unrelated classes.

@UlrichEckhardt I called Parent/Child to the classes, not to the processes

I am unsure how this question relates to the one referenced when marked as duplicate—the duplicate talks about environmental variables at the system level. Can a moderator check it?

Here is how I would create an attribute that can represent boolean values and be sharable across multiple processes. See multiprocessing.Value.
from multiprocessing import Process, get_start_method, Value
import ctypes
import time

class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        print(get_start_method())
        self.child = Child()

    def start(self):
        self.child.start_child()

    def print_child_variable(self):
        print('Parent: Child Variable:', self.child.some_variable.value)


class Child:
    def __init__(self):
        # This Value instance can only have values True and False:
        self.some_variable = Value(ctypes.c_bool, False)

    def start_child(self):
        do_something_process = Process(target=self.do_something)
        do_something_process.start()


    def do_something(self):
        self.some_variable.value = True
        print('Child: some variable after changing:', self.some_variable.value)

    def print_some_variable(self):
        print('Child: some variable:', self.some_variable.value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent = Parent()
    parent.print_child_variable()
    time.sleep(1)
    parent.start()
    parent.print_child_variable()
    time.sleep(1)
    parent.print_child_variable()
    time.sleep(1)
    parent.child.print_some_variable()

Prints:
fork
Parent: Child Variable: False
Parent: Child Variable: False
Child: some variable after changing: True
Parent: Child Variable: True
Child: some variable: True

